# Colouring juggling balls

Tags: combinatorics

Please forgive the phrasing of this question, it was the only way I could think of that gets the problem across.  Any other re-phrasings would be appreciated!  The aim is to count how many different sets of juggling balls you can make with colored panels.  Each ball has $2$ colours, red and blue say, and there are four different colours in total.  You are trying to make $2n$ balls in total and you have $2$ panels of the first colour, $2n-2$ of the second, $2$ of the third and $2n-2$ of the fourth.  As an example let's consider the colours red, blue, green and yellow.  So you have 
$$
R,B,...,B,G,Y,...,Y 
$$ 
for the first panels of each ball, with $n-1$ blues and $n-1$ yellows.  We now take all permutations of this set, I believe there are 
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!},
$$
and pair them element-wise with the first set giving as an example for $n=4$
$$
\begin{align}
& R,B,B,B,G,Y,Y,Y \\
& R,B,Y,B,G,Y,B,Y
\end{align}
$$ 
so, to repeat, I would like to know how many unique sets of the $2n$ balls are possible.  And again if anyone knows of a simpler way to phrase the problem I'm open to suggestions!  Thanks.

Comment: Should we worry about the order in which the colored panels are assigned to the balls?  In other words, is the ball $\langle R,B,B,R\rangle$ different from the ball $\langle R,B,R,B\rangle$?  Also, are monochromatic balls accepted?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear from the question.  Each ball has $2$ colours and the order doesn't matter, i.e. $R B$ is the same as $B R$.  Just to clarify, for the above example of we have $8$ balls which are coloured $R R$, $B B$, $B Y$, $B B$, $G G$, $Y Y$, $Y B$ and $Y Y$ and the balls $B Y$ $Y B$ are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are always using panels in pairs, we can just count pairs.  Let's say we have one pair each of red ($R$) and green ($G$), and $n-1$ pairs each of blue ($B$) and yellow ($Y$).

Think about where the red and green panels can be assigned: Exactly one of the following sets of balls must be present in any solution:

1. $\{RB,GB\}$
2. $\{RY,GY\}$
3. $\{RB,GY\}$
4. $\{RY,GB\}$
5. $\{RG\}$

In the first case, you are left with $n-3$ pairs of blue panels and $n-1$ pairs of yellow panels.  The second case is similar.  In the third and fourth cases, you are left with $n-2$ blue and $n-2$ yellow panel-pairs.  And in the final case, you are left with $n-1$ blue and $n-1$ yellow panel-pairs.

Here's how to compute the number of possible sets of balls if you have $n-2$ blue panel-pairs and $n$ yellow panel-pairs.  I'll leave the rest to you.

Note that once you determine the number of $YY$ balls in a set, everything else is determined.  The smallest number of $YY$ balls that we can have is 1 (not 0 - why?).  The largest number is $\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$.  The number of possible arrangements containing the set of balls listed in (1) above is therefore $\lfloor (n-3)/2\rfloor$.

The rest of the calculations are similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  If I'm following you correctly I believe you meant to write "In the first case, you are left with $n-2$ pair of blue panels" and "if you have $n-2$ blue panel-pairs and $n-1$ yellow panel-pairs"?  Aren't we neglecting duplicated colours, shouldn't we add to the list things like $\{ RB,GG\}$?

Comment: In the first case, one pair of blue panels has been combined with the red panels to make one ball, and another pair has been combined with the green panels to make a second ball. There were $n-1$ pairs to begin with, so we are left with $n-3$ pairs of blue panels and $n-1$ pairs of yellow panels. Suppose now that $k$ $YY$ balls are to be made. Then we are left with $n-1-2k$ pairs of yellow panels (which may not be used to make additional $YY$ balls). So we must make exactly $n-1-2k$ $BY$ balls, and the remaining $(n-3)-(n-1-2k)=2k-2$ pairs of blue panels must be used to make $k-1$ $BB$ balls.

Comment: ...the point being that once once you have decided to make one $RB$ and one $GB$ ball, the remaining balls are completely determined by your choice of $k$.  The number of such combinations is therefore just the number of allowable values of $k$.  Which is $\lfloor(n-3)/2\rfloor$.